# React | Change parent styling when child has class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a menu that has a dropdown menu on one of the items. When I choose one of the dropdown menu items it adds a class to it changings its styling.

I need to also change their parents styling so that the user understands that something inside that dropdown is selected but I haven't been able to wrap my head around this (I'm probably not approaching it properly).

How can I then change this parent based on one of the children having this said class?

```
class NavigationSection extends Component {
  renderInternalLinks(internal, proeminent) {
    return (
      <InternalLinksWrapper className={proeminent ? 'is-proeminent' : ''}>
        <SectionTitle>{internal.title}</SectionTitle>
        <LinkList>
          {internal.links.map(({ title, link, type, submenu }, index) => {
            switch (type) {
              case 'internal_link':
                return (
                  <li key={index}>
                    <NavigationGatsbyLink to={link}>
                      {title}
                    </NavigationGatsbyLink>
                    {submenu && submenu.length > 0 ? (
                      <SubMenu className="submenu" aria-label="submenu">
                        {submenu.map(({ link, title }, index) => (
                          <li key={index}>
                            <NavigationGatsbyLink key={index} to={link}>
                              {title}
                            </NavigationGatsbyLink>
                          </li>
                        ))}
                      </SubMenu>
                    ) : null}
                  </li>
                );

              [...]
          })}
        </LinkList>
      </InternalLinksWrapper>
    );
  }
  [...]
}
```

One item of the `SubMenu`will have the `is-active` class and I have to then change the styling of the `NavigationGatsbyLink` that comes right before `{submenu && submenu.length > 0`

`is-active` is added to `NavigationGatsbyLink` by `activeClassName`, a class that gets added to [Gatsby Link](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/) when it is active

Comment: How is 'is-active' determined? Is it strictly CSS? Or is there some context within the `submenu` array?

Comment: @technicallynick, 'is-active' is added to NavigationGatsbyLink via the activeClassName prop that Gatsby Link has

Comment: It looks like Gatsby accounted for this type of use case by including the `getProps` property on the `Link` component. I'd probably send a callback function along to the `Link` component that is a callback if the `isCurrent` or `isPartiallyCurrent` is true to color the parent component or add a class.

 https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/#use-getprops-for-advanced-link-styling

Comment: If you set up a codesandbox I can try to work with you a little more on an example.

Comment: @technicallynick, thank you, the `partiallyActive={true}` was the way to go. I tried to used `getProps` but it really wasn't doing anything but `partiallyActive` did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/#use-getprops-for-advanced-link-styling) shows that you can do advanced link styling by calling out the `getProps` property on the `Link` component. From your comment in your post, it seems all you really needed was `partiallyActive={true}`.